# Getting and passing IDs to jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a script that changes page content but within a foreach array. I have this HTML:

```
<div id="bigleftproject">

    <p>content which will be swapped</p>

</div>


<!-- thumbnails (foreach array -->
<div class="prj_thumb" id="thumb1"> 
    <h2 class="active">project 1</h2>
    <img src="../img/thumbnail1.png" alt="thumbnail" width="100" height="50" />
</div>

<div class="prj_thumb" id="thumb2"> 
    <h2 class="active">project 2</h2>
    <img src="../img/thumbnail2.png" alt="thumbnail" width="100" height="50" />
</div>

<div class="prj_thumb" id="thumb3"> 
    <h2 class="active">project 3</h2>
    <img src="../img/thumbnail3.png" alt="thumbnail" width="100" height="50" />
</div>
<!-- end -->
```

and I have the beginnings of my jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.prj_thumb').click(function() {
        $('#bigleftproject').load('http://www.mysite.com/projects/small/thumb1');
    });
});
```

Essentially, what I am trying to achieve is for the jQuery script to grab the ID of '.prj_thumb' and pass that into the final part of the URL in the .load function.

Comment: Uh, I'd simply use `.attr('id')` method, which returns the ID as a string, which you can pass anything, even to another 'jQuery selector'.

Comment: how can I pass the ID of '.prj_thumb' and pass that into the final part of the URL in the .load function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.prj_thumb').click(function() {
        $('#bigleftproject').load('http://www.mysite.com/projects/small/' + this.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Style class -

```
.btn {

}
```

Javascript (jQuery) -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".btn").each(function(index, element) {
        alert(this.id);
    }); 
});
```

HTML -

```
<div class="btn" id="btn1"></div>
<div class="btn" id="btn2"></div>
<div class="btn" id="btn3"></div>
```